# Signing PyInstaller Executables

Tags: python, windows, pyinstaller, exe, x509certificate

I attempted using signtool.exe on windows, combined with the deprecated makecert.exe which did not work, I also tried the PowerShell alternative along with makercert.exe which gave me an invalid certificate.
PowerShell command:

```
New-SelfSignedCertificate -DnsName [domain.com] -CertStoreLocation cert:\LocalMachine\My
```

When I attempt to sign the executable **bot.exe** I get this warning/error:
*"SignTool Error: No certificates were found that met all the given criteria."*
Is it possible to generate a x509 certificate for my executable for free? Is there a paid alternative?

Comment: if this is something publicly re-distributable (installed on a devices you have not control over), then you should not bother with self-signed certificates and acquire a signing certificate from a commercial and publicly trusted CA provider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, as @Crypt32 stated, it is not possible to get a publicly trusted certificate by using PowerShell or makecert.exe and I will have to get a certificate from a publicly trusted CA provider. This Microsoft Article explains the process: [Get a code signing certificate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/dashboard/get-a-code-signing-certificate#:%7E:text=Get%20a%20code%20signing%20certificate.%201%20Step%201%3A,to%20get%20a%20code%20...%20%20See%20More.)